# How to wrap every 4 elements in a <li> tag with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I need to wrap every 4 `.product` divs in a row within a `<li>` tag so that when there's:

```
<ul>
  <div class="product">...</div>
  <div class="product">...</div>
  <div class="product">...</div>
  <div class="product">...</div>
  <div class="product">...</div>
  <div class="product">...</div>
</ul>
```

it gets turned in to a:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="product">...</div>
    <div class="product">...</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the example I've given 6 products because it must close the wrapping if those are the last elements anyway.

Can you please show me how this can be done with `jquery`?

Comment: Why would the menu have that structure in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Which bit are you finding difficult? It's just: Get all product divs, loop them, add them to a `<li>` (which you add to the `<ul>`), and every 4 loops change to a new `<li>`

Comment: Need to fix source. You have invalid markup. `<div>` is not a valid child of `<ul>` therefore you can't rely on all browsers to render them inside the `<ul>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use for loop along to iterate over every 4th element and then wrap the 3  previous elements along with current 4n element using `.wrapAll()`:

```
var productdivs = $("ul .product");
for(var i = 0; i < productdivs.length; i+=4) {
  productdivs.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll("<li></li>");
}
```

### Working Demo